# Skipping First ROW of CSV File Data

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to send CSV data into my mysql database but i want to skip first row of the data because it contains header, i went through some post in here but they were not helpfully any idea how can i perform this in my below codes?????

```
//if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) { 
if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size']) && $_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) { 
//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

//loop through the csv file and insert into database
$num = count($data); 
do { 
    if ($data[0]) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO mbet_football (TIME, TEAMS, HOME, DRAW, AWAY) VALUES 
            ( 
                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                '".addslashes($data[4])."' 
            ) 
        "); 
    } 
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
// 

//redirect 
header('Location: mbetf.php?success=1'); die; 

 } 

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I little bit changed your code, but it should work:

```
<?php

  //if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) { 
  if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size']) && $_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) { 
//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 

$row = 0;

if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {   

        $row++;

        if($row == 1) continue;

        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO mbet_football (TIME, TEAMS, HOME, DRAW, AWAY) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 

    }
       fclose($handle);
   }

//redirect 
header('Location: mbetf.php?success=1'); die; 

 } 

 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just get the first line before the loop?

```
$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'");

//loop through the csv file and insert into database
while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'")) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag to skip the first row.

```
//loop through the csv file and insert into database
$skipFlag = true;
while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")){
    if($skipFlag){
        $skipFlag = false;
        continue;
    }
    if ($data[0]) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO mbet_football (TIME, TEAMS, HOME, DRAW, AWAY) VALUES 
            ( 
                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                '".addslashes($data[4])."' 
            ) 
        "); 
    }
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).